# networkx: contract adjacent nodes in a directed acyclic graph

Tags: python, graph, nodes, networkx, directed-acyclic-graphs

Zoom into my `directed acyclic graph`, you will find the adjacent nodes `(u,v,w,x,y)`. The node `w` is a the center, `u` and `v` are `upstream` and `x` and `y` are `downstream`

That results in the following edges:

```
(u,w)
(v,w)
(w,x)
(w,y)
```

[image: ![graphical representation of my dag]

I want to remove the node `w` and preserve the flow of the graph. After `w` removed, the edges should be

```
(u,x)
(u,y)
(v,x)
(v,y)
```

I thought that `networkx.contracted_nodes(G, u, w, self_loops=False)` is the way to go. But according the docs this will generate a new node, let's call it `uw` with the edges

```
(uw,x)
(uw,y)
(v,uw)
```

Which alters the behaviour of my graph and is not what I want.

Is there a way to solve it using networkx?

Comment: @d.b I have the nodes also in a pandas dataframe and can identify those that need to be removed based on some tags. They can have an arbitrary number of incoming edges and 1 or 2 outgoing edges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming edges are a list of tuples

```
def foo(arr, key):
    d = {}
    for a, b in arr:
        d.setdefault(a, []).append(b)
    
    if d.get(key) is None:
        return arr
    
    ans = []
    fill_vals = d[key]
    for a, b in arr:
        if a != key:
            if b != key:
                ans.append((a, b))
            else:
                for val in fill_vals:
                    ans.append((a, val))
                    
    return ans

data = [("u", "w"), ("v", "w"), ("w", "x"), ("w", "y")]    
foo(data, "w")
# [('u', 'x'), ('u', 'y'), ('v', 'x'), ('v', 'y')]
```